# C# NFC Proximity - Handler is not fired

Tags: c#, windows, handler, nfc, proximity

I have a serious problem with writting and reading NFC tags.
The handler is not fired.

This is my code to write some text to a NFC tag and it's working:

```
// Writes a string to a NFC tag
    private bool WriteToNFCTag(string value)
    {

            var dataWriter = new DataWriter() { UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8 };
            dataWriter.WriteString(value);

            ProximityDevice.GetDefault().PublishBinaryMessage("Windows:WriteTag.NokiaTest", dataWriter.DetachBuffer(), MesssageTransmitted);


    }

private void MesssageTransmitted(ProximityDevice sender, long messageId)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Message sent!");
        }
```

But I can't read the NFC tag:

```
ProximityDevice.GetDefault().SubscribeForMessage("Windows.NokiaTest", messageReceivedHandler);
```

doesn't fire the the *messageReceivedHandler*

```
void messageReceivedHandler(ProximityDevice device, ProximityMessage message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Got the message");
        var byteBuffer = message.Data;
    }
```

I don't get any error messages or something like that. I would be great if someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried this but it doesn't work: http://www.coderexception.com/CmHbmzBHPUXQQSSW/reading-physical-nfc-tag-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to stop the publication in the `MesssageTransmitted` method.

```
private void MesssageTransmitted(ProximityDevice sender, long messageId)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Message sent!");
    ProximityDevice.GetDefault().StopPublishingMessage(messageId);
}
```

**Update:** In recent months I have been developing a Win8.1 desktop application that writes/reads NFC tags, using `NDEF` format (protocols: "NDEF:WriteTag" to publish/"NDEF" to subscribe). I use NdefLibrary from https://ndef.codeplex.com/.

The "Windows" protocol, according to [Nokia](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/connectivity/using-nfc-to-exchange-information.html), is between devices, not between a device and a tag. So you might need to use NDEF protocols that are "between device and a tag".

[image]

also see according to [Limitations with Windows Phone 8](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Use_NFC_tags_with_Windows_Phone_8)

> Since Proximity API gives only high level access to the NFC protocol and Windows Phone adds some protection on top of that, your interaction with NFC tags is limited:
>
> You cannot format a tag. Your tag must be formatted for NDEF message.
>
> Your tag can contain only an NDEF message.
>
> Proximity API does not give tools to manipulate directly NDEF messages. To manipulate raw NDEF messages you can use NDEF Library for Proximity APIs (NFC).

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work.
It still doesn't jump to the Handler.

Comment: or it might be because `Windows` protocol is not supported. see my updated answer.